# retrieving the countries details from geonames using a sparql query

Tags: sparql, linked-data, geonames

I am trying to get specific countries informations from geonames using "Linked Data HTW Chur sparql endpoint" (url: http://linkeddata.fh-htwchur.ch/lodestar/sparql ):

```
PREFIX gn: <http://www.geonames.org/ontology#>
PREFIX wgs84_pos: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

select distinct ?country ?population ?lattitude ?longitude ?creationDate ?modificationDate
from <http://sws.geonames.org>
where { ?country gn:name ?country_name;
        gn:population ?population;
        wgs84_pos:lat ?lattitude;
        wgs84_pos:long ?longitude;
        dcterms:created ?creationDate;
        dcterms:modified ?modificationDate
}
```

The query works if I remove "dcterms:created" and "dctermes:modified" but I need both to extract the data item creation date and the last modification date

If someone could please help me

Comment: I don't think that any arbitrary RDF dataset is loaded there. Which also means there is no geonames dataset loaded at all. Why do you think so? Indeed, you can download latest Geonames RDF dump and load it into a local triple store. or you find some public SPARQL endpoint which has loaded the dataset. But hosting your own one is simple and you have full control

Comment: @UninformedUser I found another sparql endpoint "Linked Data HTW Chur sparql endpoint" where my query worked, althought it doesn't work unless I remove dcterms; created and dcterms: modified, do you have any suggestions to overcome this ?

Comment: @MohamedAmineFerradji: I would suggest updating your question post with this new problem.

Comment: @MohamedAmineFerradji not sure what you means by overcome? The data is just not contained in your new SPARQL endpoint, that's it. Why do you expect that such data exists? I checked latest Geonames 3.3 RDF dump, there is neither created nor a modified data inside.

Comment: @UninformedUser I actually downloaded ,as an example, the rdf version of the united states page in geoname ( https://www.geonames.org/6252001/united-states.html ), found out the creation date and the last modification date in the rdf document, I really need to extract them using the sparql query

Answer (score 0):

You have to distinguish between the concept and the document about this concept.

Example for the [United States](https://www.geonames.org/6252001/united-states.html):

- `https://sws.geonames.org/6252001/` (concept, i.e., the actual country)
- `https://sws.geonames.org/6252001/about.rdf` (GeoNames document about this concept)

These URIs refer to each other via `rdfs:isDefinedBy`/`foaf:primaryTopic`.

The `dcterms:created` property gives the date when the document was created, not when the country was created. The same applies to `dcterms:modified`.

---

If you don’t need to refer to the "document about the concept" in your results, you could use property paths to get the values:

```
PREFIX gn: <http://www.geonames.org/ontology#>
PREFIX wgs84_pos: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?country ?population ?lattitude ?longitude ?creationDate ?modificationDate
WHERE {

?country gn:name ?country_name ;
         gn:population ?population ;
         wgs84_pos:lat ?lattitude ;
         wgs84_pos:long ?longitude ;
         rdfs:isDefinedBy/dcterms:created ?creationDate ;
         rdfs:isDefinedBy/dcterms:modified ?modificationDate .
}
```

Otherwise you can use another variable for it:

```
PREFIX gn: <http://www.geonames.org/ontology#>
PREFIX wgs84_pos: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?country ?population ?lattitude ?longitude ?creationDate ?modificationDate 
WHERE {

?country gn:name ?country_name ;
         gn:population ?population ;
         wgs84_pos:lat ?lattitude ;
         wgs84_pos:long ?longitude ;
         rdfs:isDefinedBy ?countryDocument .

?countryDocument dcterms:created ?creationDate ;
                 dcterms:modified ?modificationDate .
}
```